# Can I connect tfs through mule anypoint studio

Tags: tfs, mule

I am new in Mule ESB application developer. I am trying to connect Visual studio Team Foundation Server through Mule anypoint studio. I installed Team Foundation Server plugin in anypoint studio. But i am unable find Team Foundation Server in anypoint studio IDE. I need maintain mule applications in Team Foundation Server for source control. Could you please suggest how to connect Team Foundation Server in Anypoint Studio. Please send any steps to follow connect to Team Foundation Server in Anypoint Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the TFS in Anypoint Studio.After installing the TFS Plugin please Follow below steps: Go to
-> Windows Menu then click on Open perspective -> it shows list of plugins and many others. then add TFS to show the TFS menu.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. You can mark your own reply as an answer. Just click the green check beside your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, Mule anypoint studio is eclipse where the tfs plugin is apparently the eclipse Team Explorer Everywhere. So have you tried this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155782(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Hi Rolf, thank you for your response. I installed tfs plugin in anypoint studio then restart studio and try to find the tfs. But unable to find this.

Answer (score 0):

To view the Team Explorer (From eclipse). Go to Window ->Show View -> Other -> Team Foundation Server -> Team Explorer. You will need to map your workspace when you configure for the first time. After that, you can check-in code either via options from Team Explorer or by right clicking on your project. (Team -> Share Project -> Team Foundation Server)

Comment: Hi Jvas, thank you for your response. It's not eclipse, its Mule esb IDE for developing Mule applications, this IDE is look like eclipse

Comment: Yes, it works the same way for MuleStudio as well. If you can't see it, could you try reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: Ok, I will try and get back to u. Thank you